# Paste an extra character in the response of an oracle record

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have a goal, I want to select the first 2 items in the list, and the last 2, convert them to a string and paste "→" between them. I wrote a code that finds these elements and converts them to a string.

```html
select t.DEVNAME
         from ( select t.DEVNAME,   
                       row_number () over (partition by keys order by SEQUENCE) rn_asc, 
                       row_number () over (partition by keys order by SEQUENCE desc) rn_desc 
                               from ASU_DEVICES t
                               where t.keys = 'STIG6JGK' 
             ) t 
where rn_asc <= 2 or rn_desc <= 2
```

my answer:

```html
B
СИЛОС 102
Конвейер 67
Конвейер 66
```

converting all elements to a string :

```html
select LISTAGG(t.DEVNAME , ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 1)
         from ( select t.DEVNAME,   
                       row_number () over (partition by keys order by SEQUENCE) rn_asc, 
                       row_number () over (partition by keys order by SEQUENCE desc) rn_desc 
                               from ASU_DEVICES t
                               where t.keys = 'STIG6JGK' 
             ) t 
where rn_asc <= 2 or rn_desc <= 2
```

```html
B,СИЛОС 102,Конвейер 67,Конвейер 66
```

I want to put this mark, "→" between them, but I cannot answer my request:

```html
B,СИЛОС 102 → Конвейер 67,Конвейер 66
```

Comment: Is this for a single record? How are you displaying it, in a report?

Comment: The "code snippet" feature is for web examples (HTML, CSS, JavaScript etc) and does not work for SQL. https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: @DanMcGhan No, the keys can be many different ones, I did below for one specific key, (below in the comment my answer is for a variant with one key), but I could not make this request universal ((

Answer (score 0):

The `unistr()` function would convert ascii/hex codes to national character set - Refer to Oracle documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions204.htm).

The hex code for right arrow is `&#x2192;`

For example:

`select unistr('\2192') from dual` would return the value `→`

With respect to your question: 
In the absence of your original table structure/data, I've mocked up the table as follows:

```
    select * from asu_devices;

    | SEQUENCE  |DEVNAME        |KEYS       |
    | 1         |B              |STIG6JGK   |
    | 2         |СИЛОС 102      |STIG6JGK   |
    | 3         |Device X       |STIG6JGK   |
    | 4         |Device Y       |STIG6JGK   |
    | 5         |Конвейер 67    |STIG6JGK   |
    | 6         |Конвейер 66    |STIG6JGK   |
```

You may try the following query:

```
    with 
    first_rows as 
     ( 
         select LISTAGG(t.DEVNAME , ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 1) first_dev
         from ( select t.DEVNAME,   
         row_number () over (partition by keys order by SEQUENCE) rn_asc 
         from ASU_DEVICES t
         where t.keys = 'STIG6JGK' 
         ) t 
         where rn_asc <= 2 
     ),
     last_rows as 
     (
         select LISTAGG(t.DEVNAME , ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 1) last_dev
         from ( select t.DEVNAME,   
         row_number () over (partition by keys order by SEQUENCE desc) rn_desc 
         from ASU_DEVICES t
         where t.keys = 'STIG6JGK' 
         ) t 
         where rn_desc <= 2 
     )
    select first_dev || ' ' || unistr('\2192') || ' ' || last_dev 
    from first_rows cross join last_rows;
```

Output:

`B,СИЛОС 102 → Конвейер 66,Конвейер 67`

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/906466/23)

Comment: Thank you, I did it almost the same way)) (below in the comments) But I want to ask for one more, I want the collie to be taken from each subquery "where t.keys = 'STIG6JGK'", it continued to work for each key individually, but don't be able to. Thank you for your help)

Answer (score 0):

My variant)

```html
WITH txn as ( select one, two,trea   from  (
SELECT  (
                                   select LISTAGG(t.DEVNAME , ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 1)
                                       from ( select t.DEVNAME,
                                         row_number () over (partition by keys order by SEQUENCE) rn_asc
                                         from ASU_DEVICES t
                                      --      where t.keys = 'STIG6JGK' 
                                       ) t 
                                            where rn_asc <= 2
                              ) AS one ,
                                   (select LISTAGG(c.DEVNAME , ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 1)
                                      from ( select c.DEVNAME,   
                                        row_number () over (partition by keys order by SEQUENCE desc) rn_desc 
                                     from ASU_DEVICES c
                                    --  where c.keys = 'STIG6JGK' 
                                        ) c
                                      where rn_desc <= 2
                             ) AS two,
                               (select keys
                                     from ASU_DEVICES
                                    --  where keys = 'STIG6JGK' 
                                      group by  keys   )  as trea
                                  
                            from dual
))


select TRIM (txn.one  || '  ⇒  '  || txn.two)  as routs  , txn.trea from txn
```